# Change daily xts values to monthly option expiration OHLCV xts in R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I would like to change daily values of an xts object to monthly expiration OHLCV data. I figured I can use `quantmod::options.expiry` to do so...

```
library("quantmod")

# get SPX daily values
SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC",from="2016-01-01",auto.assign=FALSE)

# option expiration rows/dates using options.expiry()
spx_expiry <- SPX[options.expiry(SPX),]

# spx_expiry will only return the closing values for option expiration **day**
# it is missing the OHLCV data in between expiration months. 
# The Close/Adjusted columns are correct but the Open, High, Low, Volumes
# columns are incorrect. 

# Here is what I have tried:
period.apply(SPX,INDEX=options.expiry(SPX),FUN=function(x) to.monthly(x,indexAt='firstof'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the OHLCV bars yourself, taking into account carefully the timestamps for the aggregated monthly data (do you want start or end of bar for timestamp value, etc) like so:

```
m2 <- period.apply(SPX,INDEX=options.expiry(SPX),FUN=
                    function(x) {
                      xts(x = matrix(c(coredata(Op(x))[1], max(coredata(Hi(x))), min(coredata(Lo(x))), coredata(Cl(x))[NROW(x)],
sum(coredata(Vo(x)))), nrow =1), order.by= index(x)[1])
                      })

# period.apply operates the `x` data rows between FUN(x[(INDEX[y] + 1):INDEX[y + 1]], ...)
# And you want bar timestamp to be at the start of the interval:

ep_times <- index(SPX[options.expiry(SPX) + 1])
out <- xts(order.by = ep_times[-length(ep_times)], x = m2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")))

head(out)
              Open    High     Low   Close       Volume
2016-01-19 1888.66 1947.20 1810.10 1917.78 112760980000
2016-02-22 1924.44 2052.36 1891.00 2049.58  90177630000
2016-03-21 2047.88 2087.84 2022.49 2080.73  69548230000
2016-04-18 2078.83 2111.05 2025.91 2052.32  96873130000
2016-05-23 2052.23 2120.55 2047.26 2071.22  68773770000
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!